# Website will work in subdirectory but not root directory

Tags: php

I have a PHP site that I have been testing in a subdirectory /dev and everything is working great. I moved all the files over to my root directory and now it doesn't work! I have a config.php file that is handling the code so that I can easily change directories (or so I thought). Working page is [here](http://prsnetwork.com/dev) non-working page is [here](http://prsnetwork.com/index2.php). It looks like all the files are being found but it is not being styled correctly, any troubleshooting tips or anything you guys see? I have been looking at it for days and can't find anything! Please help!

Here is my config.php code

```
<?php

// these two constants are used to create root-relative web addresses
// and absolute server paths throughout all the code

define("BASE_URL","/");
define("ROOT_PATH",$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/dev/");

$site_root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/dev/";
```

And...

```
<?php

// these two constants are used to create root-relative web addresses
// and absolute server paths throughout all the code

define("BASE_URL","/");
define("ROOT_PATH",$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/");

$site_root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/";
```

Comment: One has `script src="/dev/js/responsiveslides.js"></script>` and the other has `<script src="/js/responsiveslides.js"></script>` same thing for your CSS. Once you've fixed that, everything will be hunky dory.

Comment: Well yes, when you go to prsnetwork.com/dev the src is going to include the /dev and when you go to prsnetwork.com/index2.php the /dev will not be there. This is how it should work, am I wrong?

Comment: Your JS and CSS are pointing to different root folders in both pages, that's the reason.

Comment: I don't understand... even when I use an absolute path http://www.prsnetwork.com/css/styles.css it does not work

Comment: You also have one in `http://www.prsnetwork.com/dev/css/styles.css` so it's hard to say which one you want to use as a global file.

Comment: /dev is for development, I know this isn't the best way to do it but it is easiest for our team to look at the page before I make it live. When you go to prsnetwork.com/dev I want that to stay in the /dev directory. When you go to prsnetwork.com I want that to stay in the root directory, hence the config.php file that should be updating those paths (which it seems to be working as far as looking at inspector) but it is not reflecting on the page visually.

Comment: @user2916637: Please post your .htaccess file. It seems you're entering in a loop there.

Comment: I don't have an .htaccess file ....?

Comment: Yes, you have ;) It could be hidden by default, but the SEO links are handled by the .htaccess file, unless you have a folder for each link :) Use GoDaddy's online file manager and you'll see it.

Comment: I'm using cyberduck and selected view hidden files and did not see one. I also just created a .htaccess file and it didn't ask to overwrite anything.  This is what is there now `DirectoryIndex index.html`

Comment: Then check your /dev/ folder for .htaccess

Comment: Do you have folder named `audits` in your root folder?

Comment: Yes, I do have a folder named `audits`

Comment: All of my pages are subdirectories with an index.php file in them

Comment: Your styles.css file differs from the dev one. In order to do a clean move, do the steps from my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you have `/css/styles.css` which differs from `/dev/css/styles.css`. In order to do a clean move and to make sure you don't have 2 different versions while you think they're same:

1. Delete **everything** from your root folder **except** the `/dev/` folder.
2. Copy **everything** from your `/dev/` folder into your root folder.

It's a good idea to learn about Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), and then - use a framework. Isn't maintaining 10's or 100's index.php files a pain?

**EDIT 1:** In order to disable GoDaddy's caching mechanisms, follow this [guide](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8056/enabling-website-accelerator-developer-mode):

1. Log in to your Account Manager.
2. Click Web Hosting.
3. Next to the hosting account you want to use, click Launch.
4. From the Tools section, click Website Accelerator.
5. Click Settings.
6. Click the slider next to Developer Mode so it displays On.
7. Click Close.

Comment: I will look at mod_rewrite but for now I will continue to maintain all my index files. But, I am still getting the errors, I have tried deleting everything and uploading everything from scratch. I am still not getting the correct styles to show up! What is going on?! Thank you for all your help!

Comment: At the moment you don't have index2.php (nor index.php) in the root folder, and no access to the `/dev/` folder. Remove any `.htaccess` in `/` or `/dev`. Also, check the file/folder permissions. All links under `/dev` returns 404 at the moment.

Comment: I was trying to delete everything again and re-upload it. Everything is back up again and still not working

Comment: Delete your `/css/styles.css` and copy `/dev/css/styles.css` into `/css/styles.css`. Your development stylesheet and production stylesheet are **NOT** equal (contains different things). That is the main issue.

Comment: I see that also when I look at the inspector. Although, when I open the file from my server it is the same. I have tried to delete and re-upload numerous times. I've even tried editing it using GoDaddy's editor but in that editor it looks the same as /dev/css/styles.css For some reason the browser isn't seeing it that way, it is seeing my old style sheet.

Comment: Try to delete it using GoDaddy's file manager, and then create a new file, and paste the `/dev/css/styles.css`'s content. Double check that your local files are absolutely the same as well. Few minutes ago you deleted the old stylesheet successfully, so there is no way of uploading the correct one, while the server still serves the wrong one after the numerous 404's which I received.

Comment: I am strictly using GoDaddy's editor and file manager now instead of an FTP client. I have deleted the styles.css file, haven't replaced it with anything and am still seeing the old styles when inspecting the page.

Comment: I'm sorry, but without access to GoDaddy's panel I couldn't do anything more than that. Try to contact them instead. It is not normal . If you deleted the right file it should not be served anymore. At the moment both CSS files are available, but they're with different content.

Comment: I didn't think it was normal. I was absolutely deleting the correct file. I simply renamed the css file to styles2.css and updated my `<head></head>` section to reflect those changes and it is now working. Could the old styles doc have been cached or something somewhere? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: It seems that GoDaddy **does** have caching on their webhosting service. Check out my updated answer.